# How do i know which radio button Has been Selected using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="rb1" value="no"> No
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="rb1" value="yes"> Yes
```

when I say this `alert("Test =="+$('#radio1').attr('checked'));` I expect `false` because it's not checked but it returns `undefined`.

What is the correct statement?
Why am I getting `undefined`?

Comment: if it's not checked, there is no 'checked' attribute, thus undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post explains your exact problem: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/checking-if-certain-radiobutton-is-checked

i.e. you need to use this: `alert($('#radio1').is(':checked'));`

Comment: to sum up: if it's checked, it has a 'checked' attribute. if it's not checked, there is no 'checked' attribute, thus undefined

Answer (score 2):

You get `undefined` because the `checked` attribute only exists when the element is selected.

You can get the value of the selected element like this:

```
$('input[name=rb1]:checked').val()
```

You can check if a specific element is checked in several way, for example:

```
if ($('#radio1:checked').length) ...
```

or:

```
if ($('#radio1').is(':checked')) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// checked value
var value = $("input[@name=rb1]:checked").val();

alert("Test == " + $('#radio1').val() == value );
```